# Thunderbird > 4.x on Linux does not honour default browser

Tags: browser, thunderbird, kde-4

Under KDE 4.7 I have "chromium-browser-chromium" set as my default browser in system settings.

This works for KDE apps, but not Thunderbird.  I suspect that Thunderbird is looking for the default browser in a GTK type config place, rather than a KDE setting.

So while KDE apps open links in Chromium, Thunderbird (I am currently in tb6.0, but the same behaviour happens in previous versions) opens links in Firefox.

I know I can force the issue in prefs.js but I would like to get thunderbird to respect the system setting.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thunderbird (at least version 6 here) appears to be using the XDG [MIME actions](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/mime-actions-spec) specification. The preferences are stored in `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`, and all desktop environments are supposed to respect them.

```
[Default Applications]
text/html=chromium.desktop
x-scheme-handler/http=chromium.desktop
```

---

Older versions of Thunderbird may still be using GNOME's Gvfs for this. You can check using `gconftool-2`:

```
$ gconftool-2 --get /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/http/command
firefox %s
```

If that's the case, the best option is to configure Gvfs to use `xdg-open` for all URL schemes, which in turn should invoke the right program from *mimeapps.list*:

```
$ for scheme in http https about unknown; do
    gconftool-2 --set /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/$scheme/command \
        --type string "xdg-open %s"
done
```

Or you could try `xdg-settings`, which... honestly, I'm not sure what it does:

```
$ xdg-settings set default-web-browser chromium.desktop
```

Comment: Ah ok, this is tb6 so going by option 1, I have `text/html=chromium-browser-chromium.desktop;userapp-Firefox-JWXOSV.desktop;`.  This suggests firefox is a fallback to chromium.  The chromium desktop file definitely exists in /usr/share/applications/ and has the correct `chromium-browser %u` exec line.  I'll try removing the fallback but strange tb is not respecting the primary option.

Comment: @Paul: text/html is only for HTML files. When opening http URLs, x-scheme-handler/http is used.

Comment: Interesting.  I don't have that handler defined in .local.  However, in /usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache I have `x-scheme-handler/http=opera-browser.desktop;firefox.desktop;chromium-browser-chromium.desktop;` Which suggests opera should be first.  I get that KDE should honour the .local copy, but does it write to it?

Comment: I had to add x-scheme-handler/https as well. Otherwise, Thunderbird opens HTTP links with my preferred browser and HTTPS links with the default browser (for some definition of default).

Answer (score 0):

Here's one thing that works for me: http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1391

Basically, the idea is to set `network.protocol-handler.warn-external.http` to true. Same applies to `network.protocol-handler.warn-external.https` for https protocol and maybe `network.protocol-handler.warn-external.ftp` for FTP. After applying that, Thunderbird will ask you which program to open the URL with and allow you to remember the choice.