# Clicking a link in Thunderbird opens Firefox instead of the default browser

Tags: linux, thunderbird, kde, fedora-21

I am using KDE on Fedora 21 x86_64. I recently switched my default browser from Firefox to [Chromium](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Chromium), and this worked out very well...except for Thunderbird, which still insists on attempting to open links with Firefox.

To *attempt* to resolve this problem, I have:

- Read the Mozilla wiki entry which explains [how to set your default browser](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Setting_Your_Default_Browser) on various platforms. (Of course it is *horribly* out of date, so...) My results are below:
- Checked the default browser in KDE System Settings. It is set to `chromium` and appears to work fine. Using `xdg-open http://www.google.com/` from the command line opens Google in Chromium. But Thunderbird opens links in Firefox.

  [image: KDE System Settings]
- Set [the `network.protocol-handler.app.*` settings](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.protocol-handler.app.%28protocol%29) within Thunderbird's about:config. Despite these being explicitly set to chromium, Thunderbird still opens links with Firefox. Even after setting these to `/usr/bin/xdg-open` Thunderbird still opens Firefox, leading me to believe that these settings are actually being ignored.

  [image: Thunderbird about:config]
- Checked the `mimeTypes.rdf` file. Its relevant entries were set to open Google Chrome; no reference to Firefox appeared anywhere within it. In addition, the referenced Thunderbird configuration entries for `network.protocol-handler.warn-external.*` were already set:

  [image: Thunderbird about:config]

I have also tried:

- [Checked the `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` file](https://superuser.com/q/327156/144961). It does not appear to reference Firefox in any way.

  ```
  [Added Associations]
  application/x-extension-eml=userapp-Thunderbird-93GZAX.desktop;mozilla-thunderbird.desktop;
  audio/mpeg=vlc.desktop;
  message/rfc822=userapp-Thunderbird-93GZAX.desktop;mozilla-thunderbird.desktop;
  text/html=chromium-browser.desktop;
  x-scheme-handler/mailto=userapp-Thunderbird-93GZAX.desktop;mozilla-thunderbird.desktop;

  [Default Applications]
  application/x-extension-eml=mozilla-thunderbird.desktop
  message/rfc822=mozilla-thunderbird.desktop
  text/html=chromium-browser.desktop
  x-scheme-handler/mailto=mozilla-thunderbird.desktop
  ```

I just might be losing my mind here. What have I missed?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling Firefox?

Comment: @BigHomie Not until I'm sure I don't need any old data from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I still haven't figured out why Thunderbird does what it does, (though jason C's comment seems likely) but I have managed to get it working.

I simply stopped Thunderbird, deleted the `mimeTypes.rdf` file from the profile directory, and restarted Thunderbird. Then it prompted me for the browser to use and I was able to change it to chromium successfully.

[image: Thunderbird Launch Application]

Thunderbird then created a new `mimeTypes.rdf` file which references chromium.

Now looking for a new mail client that isn't utterly absurd, but that's a post for another site...

Comment: worked for me after trying everything else. thx !

Comment: Did you ever find another client that you enjoy using? I mean... TB is fine, and I've used it for 10+ years, but there is always this kind of lingering garbage... sigh